# huge virt memory used with opencv cv::resize

Tags: opencv, resize

I tried to resize a jpg file.Then I found that,the process was using huge amount of virt memory.I then found that the problem may be related to resize() fucntion.You can see the results in the below urls.
Here is the code.

```
int main(){                                                                                                
        Mat test;                                                                                          
        Mat image_test = cv::imread("2.jpg",1);                                                            
        resize(image_test,test,Size(640,480));                                                             
        getchar();                                                                                         
}
```

gdb
[image]]
htop
[image]]